# Question concerning one rule of the topological calculus in terms of the interior operator

Tags: general-topology

Define a topological space as a set $X$ and a function $\text{int}()$ assigning to every set $A\subseteq X$ the set $\text{int}(A)\subseteq X$ such that:

(i) $\text{int}(A\cap B)=\text{int}(A)\cap\text{int}(B)$

(ii) $\text{int}(A)\subseteq A$

(iii) $\text{int}(\text{int}(A))=\text{int}(A)$

(iv) $\text{int}(0)=0$

I want to prove, using these 4 axioms only, that:

$\text{int}(A-B)\subseteq\text{int}(A)-\text{int}(B)$

I am tempted to proceed as follow:

Set $A-B=A\cap-B$.

Then $\text{int}(A-B)=\text{int}(A\cap-B)=\text{int}(A)\cap\text{int}(-B)$

Similarly, we have $\text{int}(A)-\text{int}(B)=\text{int}(A)\cap -\text{int}(B)$

Hence, it suffices to show that $\text{int}(-B)\subseteq-\text{int}(B)$, which is true. But, in that case, the proof becomes circular, and I do not see how else I could do.

Can anybody please help? Thanks.

Comment: For (iv) do you mean $\varnothing$ instead of 0?

Comment: Also by $-B$ do you mean $X-B$?

Comment: Are $A-B$ and $-B$ your invention or you have been taught to use such symbols?

Comment: Note that axiom 4 should say $\operatorname{int}(X) = X$. What you state is a consequence of (ii) already. Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1066840/4280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not circular. Using less-than-standard notation, 
you showed that, since $A\setminus B$ = $A\cap B^c$, then 
$\text{int}(A\setminus B) = \text{int}(A\cap B^c) = \text{int}(A) \cap \text{int}(B^c)$ (by (i)). Since $\text{int}(B^c) \subseteq \text{int}(B)^c$, it follows that $\text{int}(A\setminus B) \subseteq \text{int}(A)\cap \text{int}(B)^c = \text{int}(A)\setminus\text{int}(B)$ (by monotonicity of $\cap$).

The only gap in your proof is the claim that $\text{int}(B^c)\subseteq\text{int}(B)^c$, 
but this follows from (iv) and (i). 
Since $B \cap B^c = \varnothing$, we have $\text{int}(B)\cap\text{int}(B^c) = \text{int}(\varnothing) = \varnothing$. But if two sets are disjoint, then one is contained in the complement of the other: $\text{int}(B^c) \subseteq \text{int}(B)^c$.

Comment: And note that (iv) follows from (ii).